# How to change custom columns in AspNetUsers table

Tags: asp.net, customization, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I'm very new to ASP.NET, but I've added a FirstName (string), LastName (string), and AccountType (int, which can be a 0, 1, or 2) to my AspNetUsers database. I am working in MVC 5. While I've found numerous articles about changing the password, but I'd like to add the ability to let users change AccountType.

I am aware that the Roles might have been a better option in this case, but I've implemented so much already I'd rather not change that now.

The form for the Account Type Change contains a field for the user to input his/her password (to confirm that they would like the Account Type changed, and a dropdown list giving three options whose value is either 0, 1, or 2.

In short, the user will enter their password, click an option on the dropdownlist, then click the "sumbit button" and AccountType will be changed to a different int

```
@using SouthMeckNTHS.Models
@using SouthMeckNTHS.Extensions
@model ChangeAccountViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Change Account Type";
}

<section class="engine"></section>
<section class="mbr-section article mbr-parallax-background mbr-after-navbar" id="msg-box8-7d" style="background-image: url(../assets/images/full-unsplash-photo-1438354886727-070458b3b5cf-2000x1553-39.jpg); padding-top: 120px; padding-bottom: 80px;">
<div class="mbr-overlay" style="opacity: 0.5; background-color: rgb(34, 34, 34);">
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-xs-center">
            <h3 class="mbr-section-title display-2">MANAGE YOUR ACCOUNT</h3>
            <div class="lead"><p>Change your account settings</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AccountChange", "Manage", FormMethod.Post, new { 
@class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    Html.AntiForgeryToken();
```

```
<div class="mbr-section mbr-section__container mbr-section__container--middle">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 text-xs-center">


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="mbr-section mbr-section-nopadding">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
                <div class="row row-sm-offset">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="form-control-label" for="form1-z-name">Enter your current email<span class="form-asterisk">*</span></label>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CurrentPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CurrentPassword, "", new { @class = "text-danger", @style = "color:white" })
                            <!--<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" required="" data-form-field="Name" id="form1-z-name">-->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="form-control-label" for="form1-z-name">Choose Your Account Type<span class="form-asterisk">*</span></label>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(
m => m.NewAccountType,
new SelectList(
new List<Object>
{
                                                      new { value = 0 , text 
= "Learner"  },
                                                      new { value = 1 , text 
= "Contributor" },
                                                      new { value = 2 , text 
= "Competitor"}
},
"value",
"text"
), new { @style = "border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;padding: 0.5em 1.07em 0.5em;background:  #f5f5f5;font-size: 0.875rem;border-radius: 5px;width: 100%;line-height: 1.43;min-height: 3.5em;" }
)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="mbr-section mbr-section__container" id="buttons1-r" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 5px;">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="text-xs-center"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary text-xs-center" value="CHANGE ACCOUNT TYPE" /> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
}
```

And here is part of ManageViewModels.cs:

```
public class ChangeAccountViewModel
{

   [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string CurrentPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Choose Account Type")]
    public int NewAccountType { get; set; }
}
```

So, likely in ManageController.cs, what should I add to allow the information from the first part of the form to check against the user's password and what should I add to the same file so that (if the passwords match) it will update the AccountType database with the user's choice?

(An edited copy of the "change password" function did not work)

**UPDATE**
I added this to ManageController.cs:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> AccountChange(ChangeAccountViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Get the current application user
            var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());


            //Update the details
            user.AccountType = model.NewAccountType;


            // Update user address
            var result = await UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);




        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

But it only works once. I run a test of it, I change the user's account type, and it saves to the AspNetUsers db. However, when I run it again, I can't change it anymore in ANY user accounts. What should I do to get this to work every time the user changes the dropdownlist and clicks the submit button?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to just log the user out and have them sign back in.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> AccountChange(ChangeAccountViewModel model)
    {
        //THE THING THAT ONLY WORKED ONCE:
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Get the current application user
            var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());


            //Update the details
            user.AccountType = model.NewAccountType;


            // Update user account type
            var result = await UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
                return RedirectToAction("../Account/Login");
            }
        }
        return View(model);

    }
```